# Avoid Visual Studio Focus on Debug (2012 RC)

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2012

how can I disable the feature that focuses Visual Studio when debugging starts? It is a bit of a pain, becuase I click debug, and I minimize Visual Studio as it is building, but when it finishes building Visual Studio pops back up (even with no breakpoints), and it is a bit annoying. I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 RC (Version 11.0.50706.0).

Comment: What are you looking at after you begin debugging? Visual Studio should automatically change the focus to whatever the startup project is running. For example, if its an MVC app, it should change the focus to IE.

Comment: A windows form application. It will focus on that, but it will first maximize VS.

Comment: This is happening to me too. I have a simple web app, when I am running while attached (aka "debug mode"), Chrome kept "blinking" focus... it would lose it then come back every couple of seconds. Stop debugging, and the Visual Studio 2012 stops stealing focus. I hope there is an actual solution soon.